# String case changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, lowercase

Is there any String manipulation function in Javascript or JQuery for object lowercasing / uppercasing?

I need to lowercase a string object.

Comment: You mean uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: @Josh yes, lowercase, thanks :)

i found it here :
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean changing case not cast...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Hello World!";
document.write(str.toLowerCase());

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

See [toLowerCase()](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10822.asp).

Answer (score 1):

`"abc".toUpperCase()` will give you "ABC", and `toLowerCase()` works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery:

```
 //Lowercase
 $('input#email').val($(this).val().toLowerCase());

 //Uppercase
 $('input#email').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
```